# Prove differential equation solution is even function

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Let $0\leq c<1$,$u,v,w \in C^1(\mathbb{R})$. Suppose $u'=vw ,\; v'=-uw, \; w'=-c^2 uv$ and $u(0)=0, v(0)=1, w(0)=1$
Then, for all $x\in \mathbb{R} $,$v(x)=v(-x)$ and there is $x_0$ with $v(x_0)=0$

I know that $u^2+v^2=1,\; c^2 u^2+w^2=1$ and I think I use this property in order to prove $v$ is even and has zero point.

Comment: Are you trying to prove that $v$ is even or the equalities at the bottom?

Comment: equalities at the bottom : $(u^2+v^2)'=0$ so $u^2+v^2=const$ and $u(0)^2+v(0)^2=1$

Comment: Well $u(0)^2 + v(0)^2 = 2$ not 1...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The structure $$\pmatrix{u'\\v'}=w\pmatrix{0&1\\-1&0}\pmatrix{u\\v}$$ of your equations provides the parametrization $u(t)=\sin(\alpha(t))$, $v(t)=\cos(α(t))$ for the first two components with angular velocity  $α'(t)=w(t)$, $α(0)=0$. Inserting into the third equation gives $$α''(t)=w'(t)=-c^2\sin(α(t))\cos(α(t))=-\frac12c^2\sin(2α(t)).$$ This is an equation for a physical pendulum at angle $2\alpha$ with first integral
$$
H(α(t),w(t))=w(t)^2+c^2\sin^2(α(t))=w^2+c^2u^2=1.
$$
The amplitude of the oscillation is attained at $α'=w=0$ where $|\sin(α)|=c^{-1}>1$. As that is impossible, the pendulum is in constant rotation, the angle $α$ is continuously increasing and thus also periodically passes the values $\frac\pi2+k\pi$ where $v=\cos(α)$ is zero.

Answer (score 1):

If $x\mapsto \bigl(u_0(x),v_0(x),w_0(x)\bigr)$ is the solution of the original IVP then the triple $x\mapsto \bigl(u_1(x),v_1(x),w_1(x)\bigr)$ defined by
$$u_1(x):=-u_0(-x),\quad v_1(x):=v_0(-x),\quad w_1(x):=w_0(-x)$$
is also a solution of the same IVP (check this!). The general existence and uniqueness theorem for systems of ODEs then implies that in fact
$$\bigl(u_0(x),v_0(x),w_0(x)\bigr)\equiv\bigl(u_1(x),v_1(x),w_1(x)\bigr)\ ;$$
in particular $x\mapsto v_0(x)$ is an even function.

Answer (score -1):

**First equality:**
Multiply the first equation by $u$ and the second by $v$. Adding them together yields $uu' + v v' = 0$, which is equivalent to $\frac{1}{2} \frac{d}{dx}(u^2 + v^2) = 0$. Hence $u^2 + v^2 = C$. Plugging in the initial condition implies that $u^2 + v^2 = 2$.

**Second equality:**
Hint: Multiply first equation by $c^2 u$ and third equation by $w$.

Comment: $u(0)=1$ so $u^2+v^2=1$     and you misunderstand the problem. We should prove $v$ is even function and $v$ has zero point.

Comment: @B.T.O $u(0)=0 v(0)=1$ but you are right it makes it equal to 1 not 2